# Objective-C / iOS: Subclassing UITableViewController for a custom view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

As we all know, table views in Cocoa Touch are one of the niftiest pieces of framework elements that's out there. As a convenience, Apple gave us a nice view controller class to encapsulate the functionality of a table view in a vc, the `UITableViewController`.

At the same time, there are times that we want to utilize the functionality of a table view without having it take up the whole screen. However, there seems to be no way to do this by subclassing `UITableViewController`. Instead, I had to hookup a table view and manually subscribe to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. If I try to subclass `UITableViewController`, my app crashes before it can even put the view on-screen...

My question is, is there something I'm missing? When subclassing `UITableViewController`, I hook up my custom table view to the tableView property in `UITableViewController`. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Learn to do it the normal way (delegate/datasource, etc). It's pretty easy once you've done it and much more flexible - good skill to have. Anyway... did you write the class yourself or have xcode generate it for you?

Comment: Don't subclass UITableViewController. If you need to do anything it's not giving you (and most people are), use a regular UITableView and customize it yourself. It's really only meant to be used for the simplest case.

Comment: See: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/recreating-uitableviewcontroller-to.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UITableViewController` only adds minor conveniences over `UIViewController`: it creates and positions the table view, hooks up the delegate & datasource (to itself, generally), passes the view controller `editing` property through to the table, and does a couple of useful UI bits when the view appears. (See [the docs][1] for details.)

Just about all of the above are either A) things that you're needing to change in order to have a non-fullscreen table, or B) things that you can do in a line or two each, and which `UITableViewController` only does for your convenience. For cases like this, you're better off using your own `UIViewController` subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Subclass `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`

```
MyTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Step 2: Use interface builder to drop a tableView and custom View

Step 3: Declare the tableView property as `IBOutlet` in your `MyTableViewController` header file and bind it to the tableView in the interface builder

IMHO, This process would give you more flexibility.