# Automatically Reload TableViewController On Rewind

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8, realm

I am working on an app where it starts out at a tableViewController which loads and displays data stored in a Realm database. I have it so I can create a new entry in my Realm database in a separate scene and the save button unwind segues back to the initial tableView.

I current have it so the tableViewController will reload the tableView on pull down ([something I Learned here, second answer down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475792/how-to-use-pull-to-refresh-in-swift)) but I would be better if the tableView would reload its self automatically upon unwind, displaying all the data in my database, including my new entry. Could someone please direct me to a tutorial that will teach me how this is done.

Additional info: My app is embedded in a navigation controller. The save button is located the bottom tool bar.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. All three work well.

Comment: You can accept any answer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSNotification` for that.

First of all in your `tableViewController` add this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshTable:", name: "refresh", object: nil)
}
```

And this will call one method from your class:

```
func refreshTable(notification: NSNotification) {

    println("Received Notification")
    tableView.reloadData()   //reload your tableview here
}
```

So add this method too.

Now in your next view controller where you add new data into data base add this in you `unWindSegue` function:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refresh", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading your tabledata in `viewWillAppear` in initial (tableview)controller.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.reloadData() 
 }
```

Or call again the function through which you are loading your data from Realm like

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
         getMyData() //or whatever your function name is
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboard unwind segue, try using

```
func unwindSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        getData()
        self.tableView.reloaddata()
    }
}
```