# swift auto refresh Cell

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, io, reload

which I add or remove from another ViewController
Im display this array.count in tableView
How in swift I can auto updates cell for array.count?
without Timer and Pull to refresh

Or how can I make refresh when loadedCart.count haw change?
Thanks

```
class TestTABLEVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewT: UITableView!

var CellT = TestTableViewCell()
var def = UserDefaults.standard
var loadedCart = [[String:Any]]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableViewT.estimatedRowHeight = 100

    tableViewT.dataSource = self
    tableViewT.delegate = self

    loadedCart = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "cartt") as? [[String: Any]] ?? [] 

   //Here need add auto update
 }
```

cell for row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell

    let item = loadedCart[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLbl?.text = item["name"] as? String
    cell.priceLbl.text = item["price"] as? String
    cell.qntLbl.text = item["qty"] as? String
    let im = item["image"] as? NSData
    cell.PhoroUmage.image = UIImage(data: im! as Data)



    return cell
}
```

Btn, when click - remove arr and reload cells

```
@IBAction func Btn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    def.removeObject(forKey: "cartt")
    print("remove is OK")
  //Here need add auto update when btn pressed
}
```

Comment: do you mean tableViewT.reloadData() ?

Comment: reloadData cant auto update my cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use reactive programming for this. For example [Bond framework](https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/Bond) can be used like this:

```
let todoItems: SafeSignal<[TodoItem]> = ....
let tableView: UITableView = ...
class TodoItemCell: UITableView Cell { ... }

...

todoItems.bind(to: tableView, cellType: TodoItemCell.self) { (cell, item) in
    cell.titleLabel.text = item.name
}
```

Using this framework, your table view will automatically reload when there are any changes to the source array. You will find more about usage on table views at [this link](https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/Bond/blob/master/Documentation/DataSourceSignals.md).

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to use notifications.  i.e. send a notification when something new gets added to your cart.

Then set up an observer and, every time the observer notices a change, update the tableview with reload data.

A similar use case is listed here I think but would need to be adapted for your needs (if you need more help someone more expert than me will be able to help probably with the specifics!) [Automatically Reload TableViewController On Rewind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869954/automatically-reload-tableviewcontroller-on-rewind)

Comment: Im add notifications in viewDidLoad like this    
`override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableViewT.estimatedRowHeight = 100

        tableViewT.dataSource = self
        tableViewT.delegate = self
        
        loadedCart = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "cartt") as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: "refreshTable:", name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)`
And add func  but its not work

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let carts = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "cartt") as? [[String: Any]] {
        loadedCart = carts
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.tableViewT.reloadData()
    }
}
```