# Pull to Transition to Next View

Tags: ios, swift2, tableview

I am trying to figure out how to do this in a `table view` in `swift`. Each time the user pulls the view beyond a certain threshold, and lets go, the view should trigger a perform segue. I know how to transition with a button but I am not sure how to do this. Does anyone have any ideas or a link to where I can do find the information? This image was taken from the Day One App but i believe Clear also does the same. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Look at the link https://github.com/dekatotoro/PullToRefreshSwift which similar to display the loading.

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma Awesome. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer for "Pull down to refresh" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475792/how-to-use-pull-to-refresh-in-swift)

If you want to custom the icon, see [this tutorial](http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/)

Comment: This is a really thin answer;  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers Next time, consider possibly elaborating each link, and, if the question is a duplicate, flag it.

Comment: @dfri It's not really duplicate, because he want to customize the icon. Anyway, thank for reminding me.