# UIRefreshControl not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I have a table view app with some refresh code (as in below). I have also enabled refreshing in my `Main.storyboard`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}

func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

When I pull to refresh in my app, the table view does not refresh its JSON data. How do I fix this? I am using a `UITableViewController`, not a `UITableView`.

Comment: You need to actually go to your server and get the new data when you refresh

Comment: @dan How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How do you get the data to populate your tableView ?

Comment: Take whatever you did to get the original data and do it again

Comment: @dan This worked! Thank you! You can put it as an answer, and I'll accept it if you want.

Comment: You need to check your `refresh` function here you can see more details [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475792/how-to-use-pull-to-refresh-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475792/how-to-use-pull-to-refresh-in-swift) Thanks