# Pull to refresh not performing refreshing function?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I am coding an app and have a set up queryAndAppend functions that query a DB and append the info pulled to a set of arrays (which are then used to iterate through cells in a table view). The query functions work appropriately  as they are called in the `viewDidLoad()`. I want a pull to refresh function to additionally call the functions (and thus update the table cells) but it is not working properly. Here is the relevant code:

```
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            myQueryandAppend(completion: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

            upComingQueryandAppend(completion: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

            refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
            refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
            refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainPageVC.refresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

        }
        func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject){

            myQueryandAppend(completion: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

            })
            upComingQueryandAppend(completion:{

                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

            })

        }
```

Not entirely sure why its not working as I have a very similar set up in a different view controller (with a different query/append function) that works properly with pull to refresh.

Comment: r u using tableviewcontroller? and can you show myQueryandAppend code?

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475792/how-to-use-pull-to-refresh-in-swift-2?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: @Sahil it turns out the issue was that, since I was not using a `tableViewController` and instead had a `tableView` in a regular VC, I needed the additional line of code: `tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)`. The link that Kevin provided helped a lot.

Comment: yes. you needed to add tableView.addSubview(refreshControl) if you are not using tableviewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class is a `UIViewController` but not a `UITableViewController`, you need to add the `refreshControl` as a subview to the `tableView` manually:

```
tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

So, `viewDidLoad()` should looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    myQueryandAppend(completion: {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    upComingQueryandAppend(completion: {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainPageVC.refresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    // here is the extra job!
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 10+ you can just assign the refresh control directly to a tableview / scrollview's .RefreshControl property

```
tableView.RefreshControl = refreshControl
```