# "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" for extension implementing pull to refresh for Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to add an extension to add pull to refresh to Table View. This is the reference answer which I'm following https://stackoverflow.com/a/33255722/6307359

My code throws error "**unrecognized selector sent to instance**"

Following is my code. Can anyone please look into it and let me know where I'm doing it wrong?

Tx in advance.

**Extension.swift**

```
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

public extension UIViewController
{
    func addPullToRefresh(tableView: UITableView, refreshMethodName: String){

        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector(refreshMethodName), for: .valueChanged)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        } else {
            tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        }

    }

    func pullToRefreshEnd (){

        refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.addPullToRefresh(tableView: statementsTable, refreshMethodName: "pullToRefresh")

}

// Pull to refresh implementation
func pullToRefresh() {

    // some action here
    self.pullToRefreshEnd()

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the complete error message. You left off the most important part of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding @objc before method implementation in ViewController.swift. No other changes needed.

```
// Pull to refresh implementation
@objc func pullToRefresh() {

    // some action
    self.pullToRefreshEnd()
}
```