# How To Apply Refresh Control To UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to apply a refresh control to a `UITableView` which is set in a `UIViewController`?

The solution I found requires subclassing of `UITableViewController`, which is troublesome for me because I need to subclass a `UIViewController` not a `UITableViewController`, and I don't see any method under the documentation of `UITableView` that allows me to set a refresh control on it.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please check:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291537/pull-to-refresh-uitableview-without-uitableviewcontroller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pull to refresh UITableView without UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291537/pull-to-refresh-uitableview-without-uitableviewcontroller)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this `UIRefreshControl` control :

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[Delivered_TBL addSubview:refreshControl];


- (void)refresh1:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
    [self Service_Call];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Comment: This could be potential harmful as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233147/header-displaced-in-tableview-with-uirefreshcontrol
Please fix or mark as duplicated

Answer (score 2):

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[refreshControl addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(getLatestData)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[yourTableviewName addSubview:refreshControl];


   -(void)getLatestData
{
 // here add your reload method
  [self XXXXX]; 

  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
   NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last update: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
   NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                    forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
   NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attrsDictionary];
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = attributedTitle;

        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
```

Comment: it working fine bro, if u have any trouble on this please ask me,