# UIRefreshControl is not working in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I have added a `UIRefreshControl` to my collection view:

```cc
 self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshCV:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.collectionView addSubview:self.refreshControl]; 

- (void)refreshCV:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh{ 
      NSLog(@"Refresh");
      [refresh endRefreshing];
}
```

But it is not working always. In other words, sometimes when pulling down it is doesn't call the refresh function. How to solve this?

Comment: are you using a UITableViewController, or is it just a UITableView in a normal UIViewController?

Comment: if the latter, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26033824/1219956)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718850/uirefreshcontrol-beginrefreshing-not-working-when-uitableviewcontroller-is-ins

Comment: im sorry but what is addRefreshControl method? this is the first time I encounter this.

Comment: @Joshua just addSubview

Comment: @kb920 that question is for programmatically refreshing. this is not what I need

Comment: [self.collectionView setBounces:YES];
[self.collectionView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES]; set these properties

Answer (score 2):

Try this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693598/2284065). 
You have to set `alwaysBounceVertical` property of collection view.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark UIRefreshControl

- (void) setUpRefreshControl {
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    //add UIRefreshControl to Collection view
    [self.collectionView addSubview:refreshControl];
}

- (void)refresh:(id)sender 
{
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = (UIRefreshControl *)sender;

    // End the refreshing
    if (refreshControl) {
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `UITableViewController` class, then do as below

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewController.tableView = self.myTableView;
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTV:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
tableViewController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;

- (void)refreshTV:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh{ 
      NSLog(@"Refresh");
      [refresh endRefreshing];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a UIRefreshControl.

```
UIRefreshControl *control = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
control.tintColor = someColor;
[control sizeToFit];
[tableView addSubview:control];
```

Answer (score 0):

You add `refreshCV` as the target function for refresh control while you actually have `refreshTV` below. Please check to make sure which function you want indeed.

Comment: by mistake while typing the Question